# How to calculate the time difference in microseconds between two timestamps using the Boost library

Tags: c++, boost, time

UPDATE: code now compiles properly

I would like to calculate the time difference between two timestamps. The resolution is important so it must be in microseconds/milliseconds.

I tried the following but the result is not meaningful:

```
boost::posix_time::ptime before = (&input[0])->timestamp;
boost::posix_time::ptime now = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();

boost::posix_time::time_period tp (before, now);
std::string str (boost::posix_time::to_simple_string (tp));
cout << str.c_str() << endl;
```

The result i get is the following:

```
[2014-Jun-20 12:26:07.711182/2014-Jun-20 12:26:07.711596]
```

How can i get something like the following instead?

```
76 μs
```

Comment: Please post the _relevant_ (Don't fill the room) errors ?

Comment: Do you simply need to qualify the namespace of `to_simple_string` i.e. `boost::posix_time::to_simple_string`?

Comment: Wow,so simple that i just overlooked it!

Comment: Here are a number of other methods: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728068/how-to-calculate-a-time-difference-in-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use

```
std::cout << (now - before).total_microseconds() << " µs\n";
std::cout << (now - before).total_milliseconds() << " ms\n";
```

This does exactly what you want (printing e.g. `76 µs` or `314 ms`)

Answer (score 4):

I recomend to use boost::chrono

```
boost::chrono::system_clock::time_point before =
        boost::chrono::system_clock::now(); 
//do some work
boost::chrono::system_clock::time_point now =
        boost::chrono::system_clock::now(); 
boost::chrono::nanoseconds t = boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::nanoseconds>(now-before);
std::cout << t.count() << "\n";
```

Why boost chrono? [Boost.Chrono vs. Boost.Date_Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730422/boost-chrono-vs-boost-date-time)

If you need a very simple solution(without boost linking) just use:

```
inline unsigned long long getCurrentNanos()
{
    timespec tv;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tv);

    return tv.tv_sec*1000000000 + tv.tv_nsec;
}
//...
unsinged long long start = getCurrentNanos();
//do some work
std::cout << getCurrentNanos() - start << '\n';
```

Comment: Why is the use of boost::chrono better?

Comment: Boost chrono most focused on time intervals(as you can see the resolution can be in nanoseconds) and aslo implements (copied from boost doc): "the new time facilities in C++0x, as proposed in N2661 - A Foundation to Sleep On. That document provides background and motivation for key design decisions and is the source of a good deal of information in this documentation".